# Recursive function outputs double results?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am new to writing recursive functions and am a bit stuck on something. I can't work out why this function outputs to the console twice... Take a look:

`keyName = 'code'`

```
// check, recursively, if an object contains an array
let concatObject = function(obj) {
    // get the keys of the parent object
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    // for each child object in the parent object
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        // get the current child
        let key = keys[i];
        // get the keys of the current child
        let intKeys = Object.keys(obj[key]);
        // for each child object in the child object
        for (let p = 0; p < intKeys.length; p++) {
            // get the nested child
            let intKey = intKeys[p];
            // if it's an array, repeat above steps by calling current function
            if (!Array.isArray(obj[i][intKey])) {
                // if it's not an array, get the value according to the passed keyName, checking for undefined
                if (typeof obj[i][keyName] !== 'undefined') {
                    console.log(obj[i][keyName]);
                }
            } else {
                console.log('FOUND ARRAY');
                concatObject(obj[i][intKey]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Annnd the passed object (obj):

```
{
    code: "10", name: "Games",
    subCategories: [
        {code: "10_34", name: "Action"},
        {code: "10_35", name: "Adventure"},
        {code: "10_36", name: "Arcade"},
        {code: "10_37", name: "Board"},
        {code: "10_38", name: "Card"},
        {code: "10_39", name: "Casino"},
        {code: "10_40", name: "Casual"},
        {code: "10_41", name: "Dice"},
        {code: "10_42", name: "Educational"},
        {code: "10_43", name: "Family"},
        {code: "10_44", name: "Kids"},
        {code: "10_45", name: "Music"},
        {code: "10_46", name: "Puzzle"},
        {code: "10_47", name: "Racing"},
        {code: "10_48", name: "Role Playing"},
        {code: "10_49", name: "Shooter"},
        {code: "10_50", name: "Simulation"},
        {code: "10_51", name: "Sports"},
        {code: "10_52", name: "Strategy"},
        {code: "10_53", name: "Trivia"},
        {code: "10_54", name: "Word"},
        {code: "10_55", name: "MMO"},
        {code: "10_57", name: "Gambling"},
        {code: "10_58", name: "Animals", animals: [
            {dog: "bark"},
            {cat: "meow"}
        ]}
    ]
},
```

The output, un(?)expectedly, is:

```
10
10
FOUND ARRAY
10_34
10_34
10_35
10_35
10_36
10_36
10_37
10_37
10_38
10_38
10_39
10_39
10_40
10_40
10_41
10_41
10_42
10_42
10_43
10_43
10_44
10_44
10_45
10_45
10_46
10_46
10_47
10_47
10_48
10_48
10_49
10_49
10_50
10_50
10_51
10_51
10_52
10_52
10_53
10_53
10_54
10_54
10_55
10_55
10_57
10_57
10_58
10_58
FOUND ARRAY
```

The filter is working (the passed keyName is 'code' and so the doubly nested array key names shouldn't be showing) however with my current implementation any logic I use here will trigger twice, and I don't want that!

Help appreciated, thanks all!

Comment: I just realized I am not showing how I call the function. I do it within a switch statement, like so:

`concatObject(obj);` 

And I am 100% sure I'm calling it once (initially).

Comment: For each object in your subCats array, the inner loop (var p) will loop twice, once for each key in object ('code' and 'name'). It will log the value of 'code' during each loop since you've hard coded that as the value of keyName var. Try changing console.log(obj [i][keyName]) to console.log (obj [i][intKey]) and your problem will be a bit more clear

Comment: What is the intended output? `concat(obj)` doesn't make sense. Concat obj to/with what?

Comment: The logic will be adding a suffix and optional prefix (a string, or array of strings) to the object key names - basically writing a serializer which outputs an SQL like query, or whatever else, based on passed strings. That part works - but it happens twice. Logging `ob[i][intKey]` produces expected output (each key value pair, only once)...

Comment: If you down vote, feel free to say why and I will try to correct or improve the question. Down voting without feedback is a bit rich - sharing is caring - let's share our criticisms and solutions in a constructive way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Cmaddux for pointing out the flaw in my logic. Since I'm iterating over each key present in each object I need to make sure the function only acts when the right condition is met, i.e. when the passed value `keyName` is being acted on.

Changing my IF condition to this solved it:

`if ((typeof obj[i][keyName] !== 'undefined') && intKey === keyName)`

Lesson learned: never assume. I thought it was some funky thing inside of the recursive stack, when, low and behold, human error prevails.